# Google Spreadsheet Cycler

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

First of all, I know I've posted something similar to this previously, but i got one response that I couldn't understand and that was it. So, I am trying to make an app script for google sheets to be able to increase the value of the number in a specific cell every weekday. I already know how to set up the time-based trigger for the timing, so all I need is the actual code. I know very minimal about coding, and this is the best I could come up with:

```
    function onEdit(e) {
    var range = e.range
    var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1).setValue(e.(e + 1));
    }
```

When I try to run it, it says:

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined.(line 2,file"")
```

Any ideas on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated! But please, please put it in terms that a noob can understand!

Comment: If you are running the code from the script editor instead of editing the sheet, nothing is getting passed to `e`.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have now is on the right track but with a bit of a misunderstanding.
The onEdit trigger IS a trigger, but it is not a timebased one.  onEdit is called every time a cell is edited in the spreadsheet.  If you are calling this function from a time-based trigger, it will not pass an event object (e) like it would if it were triggered by an edit, which is why you are getting your error. 
Instead, modify your time based trigger to call a different function that doesn't depend on an event object.
My understanding is that it is a static cell that you are incrementing (what I mean by this is that it will always be in the same place) so my suggestion is to grab the spreadsheet, grab the appropriate sheet, grab the cell, and edit its contents, similar to what you are already doing but more manual.  In code, it would look like this :

```
function incrementCell(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('SheetName');
  var value = sheet.getRange('B2');  
  value.setValue(value.getValue() + 1);
```

}

Simply substitute your sheets name and your cells A1 Notation location into the code and point your time-drive trigger to this function and it should work for you.

Comment: I tried using the code given, replacing 'Sheetname' and 'B2' with the corresponding info and the cell i put this in returned:

Comment: You do not have permission to call setValue (line 4).

Comment: Any ideas, or is it not possible?

Comment: Try running the script manually from the script editor and see if you get the same error.  We can figure it out from there.  What you are trying to do should 100% be possible!

Comment: Running the code in the script editor doesn't return any errors.

Comment: Then it is an issue with the trigger.  I think I may have made a mistake in my code by calling getActiveSpreadsheet().  I'm not 100% sure that the trigger knows which sheet that line with this.   
`var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.('SpreadsheetId').getSheetByName('SheetName'); `

Replace SpreadsheetId with the id of your spreadsheet then give it a go.  Hopefully that will fix the issue.  Also, make sure the trigger is created by the same user account that is able to successfully run it from the editor.

Comment: Running it with that line replaced in the script editor returns the error:          SpreadsheetApp is not an XML object.(line 2,file"").

Comment: That is very odd.   What exactly are you putting in for the ID?  Is it possible for you to share your code with me so I can see exactly what is going on? jonathan.j.seed@gmail.com is my email.